# Android App crashes with ClassNotFoundException only in Redmi Note 3, Note4

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, jvm-arguments

I have generated one debug APK. When I installed it on device it's working fine. But for few devices like Redmi Note3, Redmi Note4 (both are Marshmallow versions) when i install the app they are crashing says ClassNotFoundException. But when I set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m in gradle.properties it's working fine in all devices. If i Remove the line its not working on above mentioned devices. I disabled MIUI optimizations and cleaned storage. I would like to know why it is happening with those particular devices.

```
Suppressed:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.baasu.demoapp.MainApplication at java.lang.class.classForName(Native Method) at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:504) ...12more

Caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Class not found using the boot class loader;no stack trace available
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` for which class ? Add the crash stacktrace with question

Comment: The MainAppication itself showing as CNF Exception.

Comment: Do you know how to add proguard file.

Comment: @shohruhMaxmudov I have added proguard for release builds only.

        **release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }**

Comment: @baasu I mean with Keeping files.